# Why webmasters use `ul/li` instead of `div`s for layout?

Tags: javascript, html, css

As far as I know `ul / li` are typography specific tags, intended to format text as a list (while search engines love semantic tags).

My big question here is why Web Masters prefer to use lists solution (ul/li) where is an obvious case of a layout (div) solution, preferring to modify a lot of style for list semantic tags making it look like a div solution?

Are they just mistakes of use or I'm missing important facts here?

I'm asking this because, in many cases this is valid for a lot of widget plug-ins out in wild, which generate the html code dynamically (via `JavaScript`), even though some search engines don't support (or have limited support of) `JavaScript`. ex : `FlipClockJs`, Bootstap Components (carousel, nav, pagination), etc.

Comment: *"typography specific tags"* Says who? It is a list. Has nothing to do with styling. You can have list of information. "*The HTML unordered list element (<ul>) represents an unordered list of items, namely a collection of items that do not have a numerical ordering, and their order in the list is meaningless." - [MDN ul](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul)*

Comment: You use `ul`/`ol` to mark up _lists_ of items – that answer is as obvious as it is trivial. And semantic HTML is not just about search engines.

Comment: UL/LI are list tags, so for lists of information, such as navigation.

Comment: Are you talking in terms of navigation menus? It's pretty standard to see navigation laid it using lists, but I agree that using `divs` would be a better approach. So does [this guy](http://bfreemore.blogspot.com/2011/01/web-accessibility-with-reinhard-stebner.html).

Comment: It seems like you're asking "Why do web developers go through the pains of using semantically correct (but difficult-to-style) list elements, when they could use `<div>`s which are easier to style (but semantically less valuable)?" Is that correct, or am I projecting my own understanding of the situation onto your question?

Comment: @apsillers Yes, I trying to find out what's the real value of using list tags in a layout since is not a SEO optimisation.

Comment: @epascarello  I do! Just from context lists seems to be more in the `typography` section than in `layout` section. Is just that there is a default/implicit style for them natively and in a typical write/word program one have the list next to the the indentation and numbering, (and html seems to be very much inspired from word processing programs)

Comment: @Chad No, I'm asking in general why would one would prefer list (ul/li) for layout than (divs).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> As far as I know ul / li is are typography specific tags, intended to format text as a list (while search engines love semantic tags).

They are not. They are semantic elements that say the content is a set of list items where the order is not of particular importance.

> My big question here is why Web Masters prefer to use lists solution (ul/li) where is an obvious case of a layout (div) solution

Divs are not related to layout. Layout is the job of CSS. The elements used should be selected based on the semantics they convey, then CSS should be applied to them to give the desired rendering.

A div element is an element of last resort. It has no semantics and should be used when HTML doesn't have an element with appropriate semantics for the content.

Comment: I respectfully disagree that a div element is an element of 'last resort'.  Divs are useful as they are flexible, diverse, and can solve many styling issues without removing initial browser-based rendering of elements.  For instance with ul/li you have to remove the list-style-type, fix padding, margin, etc... to use as navs or whatever, and give them block attributes if relevant.  I think li tags have their benefits, but true to the original poster's question, may be overused in some instances.  Many times people use ul/li without the semantic need for it.

Comment: Some developers do have a tendency to see everything as a list, which is a problem, but "having to change the default style" is a really poor reason to avoid using semantic markup when it is the correct semantic markup.

Comment: @MiaMarks The HTML5 spec says the div element is an element of last resort: http://developers.whatwg.org/grouping-content.html#the-div-element

Comment: Hi @Rob... First the wording is not as explicit as 'it is an element of last resort' - it says authors are strongly encouraged to 'view' divs as a last resort WHEN no other element is suitable, which is often the case.  Not everyone is using html5 yet though across the board.  It's a catch-all question I thought, including support for more browsers and such.  In that same spec it says: "On the other hand, div elements can be useful for stylistic purposes ..."

Answer (score 6):

`ul`/`ol`/`li` are not *typographic* tags, they're *semantic* tags (tags that have a meaning). Lists are commonly used for lists of navigation links and similar because:

1. Conceptually — indeed, *semantically* — a navigation menu *is* a list of places you might want to go, after all; and
2. The *unstyled* version is easily understood (as a list)

E.g., styled:

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
li > a {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1px;
}
li > a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#this">This</a></li>
  <li><a href="#that">That</a></li>
  <li><a href="#the-other">The other</a></li>
</ul>
```

Unstyled:

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#this">This</a></li>
  <li><a href="#that">That</a></li>
  <li><a href="#the-other">The other</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Right. Always consider those who view your website via a screenreader or other assistive technology. The document should make sense as raw HTML from a user's perspective.

Comment: @isherwood if you do care about screenreaders, dont use <ul> https://css-tricks.com/navigation-in-lists-to-be-or-not-to-be/

Comment: @marc.d: See [the wrapup on that](https://css-tricks.com/wrapup-of-navigation-in-lists/), which largely comes to the opposite conclusion.

Comment: Interesting. I've worked with a number of accessibility consultants as a UI developer and have not had any tell me that lists were troublesome.

Answer (score 2):

I had never given any thought to the idea of lists being typographic specific before but this question made me wonder if lists were inappropriate for layout. The HTML5 spec doesn't say anything that I could immediately find to agree with that but one aside is in [the li specification](http://developers.whatwg.org/grouping-content.html#the-li-element):

> While it is conforming to include heading elements (e.g. h1) inside li
> elements, **it likely does not convey the semantics that the author**
> **intended**. A heading starts a new section, so **a heading in a list**
> **implicitly splits the list** into spanning multiple sections.

This gives rise to questioning whether lists are appropriate for all layout situations. If you are using lists to show a group of products, and those products are written using sectioning elements, does that put them under the problem called out by the quote above?

Answer (score 1):

Lists are good for defining hierarchical navigation and submenu items.  They are preferred in this case for the fact that it can be easier to target them with styling.  Webmasters also prefer using lists also because they are accessibility-friendly for screen-readers.  However, now `<nav>` is accessible friendly too. I may be the lone devil's advocate here by saying they are not as important to front-end as they used to be.  Even as semantic markup.